# How can ı get latest version of a package from pkg.go.dev with python

Tags: json, go, request, version

I need a link or something for request latest version. If it can be a link like json link . It helps me to much.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an info about latest package version like this:

```
curl https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/@latest

// response {"Version":"v1.8.1","Time":"2022-06-06T13:01:40Z"}
```

You can then get the latest package as a zip archive at this address:

```
https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin/@v/v1.8.1.zip
```

You can find more info here: https://go.dev/ref/mod#goproxy-protocol